# Closing in and makes your move

Tags: meaning

Riley Andersen in Inside Out Animation play hockey and say :

> Andersen makes her move. She's closing in!

1)What does it mean " makes her move"???

2) What does it mean "closing in" , can we change it with "She's getting closer" ???

Comment: It means exactly what it says, in any sport you have to take some kind of action, in chess you MOVE a piece, in hockey, players do something more physical, closing in, probably means she is going closer to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

`Makes her move,` in this context, means she's in *action*; `closing in` here means she's close to making a goal.

You can check the [entire transcript here.](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_Out) The statement in question follows the result - hitting the goal i.e. scoring.

> *Riley: "She's lining up for the shot she shoots and **she scores yeah.**"*

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a sport, to "make a move" means variously to "go into action", to "try to score" or to "outmaneuver a defender".  In many cases it doesn't really mean anything in particular, as it's just something sports announcers say to fill up time.

> Jones is **making a move**, he's coming around the outside!  But then Smith comes from behind to take the ball away! And we have another free kick.

I'm sure you have similar phrases in your own native language.  In the movie, Riley is just pretending she's the announcer of the hockey game, reporting on the action.

"Closing in" is similar.  It's a *hunting* expression:

> Here we can see the cheetah **closing in** on the unsuspecting gazelle, who can't see her in the tall grass.

Again, it's just something sports announcers say to make the game seem more exciting, that the player is "closing in" on the goal.  It doesn't necessarily mean they are likely to score, only that they are *getting closer* to scoring.